# Invertibility of "sum" of processes

Tags: time-series, moving-average

I know that given a moving average process in the form $$X_t= \Theta(B) \varepsilon_t$$then $X_t$ is invertible if the roots of $\Theta(B)$ are outside the unit circle. But what about something in the form
$$X_t= a + \Theta(B) \varepsilon_t ?$$
It seems to me that $X_t -a $ is invertible if the roots of $\Theta(B)$ are outside the unit circle but intuitively nothing guarantees that $X_t$ is invertible too.

Comment: Isn't it the case that the first difference process, $$X_t-X_{t-1}=X_t-BX_t=\Theta(B)\varepsilon_t - B\Theta(B)\varepsilon_t = (1-B)\Theta(B)\varepsilon_t$$ is in the first form with the polynomial $\Theta(B)$ replaced by $(1-B)\Theta(B)$? The roots of this new variable are $1$ adjoined to the roots of $\Theta$ (with multiplicity). If this is the thing you're interested in, what is the question?